# Google API - Oauth Refresh Token - Powershell

Tags: powershell, google-api, google-oauth

I'm writing a script that will download Google sheets using an Oauth access token. The script works just fine, but I'm having issues **refreshing** my access token.

Every guide I have found online shows me some iteration of the following:

```
 $refreshTokenParams = @{ 
      client_id=$clientId;
      client_secret=$secret;
          refresh_token=$refreshToken;
      grant_type='refresh_token';
    }

$refreshedToken = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token" -Method POST -Body $refreshTokenParams 

$accesstoken = $refreshedToken.access_token
```

When I run this script it returns the following:

```
    StatusCode        : 200
StatusDescription : OK
Content           : <!doctype html><html lang="en" dir="ltr"><head><base href="https://accounts.google.com/"><script data-id="_gd" nonce="<Hidden just in case>">window.WIZ_global_data =
                    {"Mo6CHc":-<Hidden just in case>,"O...
RawContent        : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
                    X-Frame-Options: DENY
                    Vary: Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site
                    google-accounts-embedded: 1
                    Pragma: no-cache
                    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
                    Strict-Transport-Security: max-...
Forms             : {}
Headers           : {[X-Frame-Options, DENY], [Vary, Sec-Fetch-Dest, Sec-Fetch-Mode, Sec-Fetch-Site], [google-accounts-embedded, 1], [Pragma, no-cache]...}
Images            : {}
InputFields       : {}
Links             : {@{innerHTML=Learn more; innerText=Learn more; outerHTML=<A href="https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2" target=_blank jsname="erTfTe">Learn more</A>;
                    outerText=Learn more; tagName=A; href=https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2; target=_blank; jsname=erTfTe}, @{innerHTML=Help; innerText=Help; outerHTML=<A
                    href="https://support.google.com/accounts?hl=en" target=_blank>Help</A>; outerText=Help; tagName=A; href=https://support.google.com/accounts?hl=en; target=_blank},
                    @{innerHTML=Privacy; innerText=Privacy; outerHTML=<A href="https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=US&amp;hl=en&amp;privacy=true" target=_blank>Privacy</A>; outerText=Privacy;
                    tagName=A; href=https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=US&amp;hl=en&amp;privacy=true; target=_blank}, @{innerHTML=Terms; innerText=Terms; outerHTML=<A
                    href="https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=US&amp;hl=en" target=_blank>Terms</A>; outerText=Terms; tagName=A; href=https://accounts.google.com/TOS?loc=US&amp;hl=en; target=_blank}}
ParsedHtml        : System.__ComObject
RawContentLength  : 1759969
```

When I save this output to an HTML file, I get this
[Error 400: invalid_request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DncaT.png)

The error says "Required parameter is missing: response_type"

[This Google doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server) mentions response_type='code' and I've added that to my array and that had no impact.

I feel like [this section in the guide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUHR9.png) SHOULD work, but it doesnt. Unless maybe I'm implementing it wrong?

I have tried using "Invoke-restmethod" while specifying the content type to json/application, I've used alternative URIs and I've quadruple checked my client ID and password. I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.

If anyone has experience with refreshing Oauth access tokens using Powershell I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this a while ago for gmail api [GmailSendMail.psi](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/55115de5e8b366be3969b24884f30a39)

The issue is how you are sending the post body.  It needs to be in the query parameters format.

```
function RefreshAccessToken([string]$clientId,[string]$secret, [string]$refreshToken){

   $data = "client_id=$clientId&client_secret=$secret&refresh_token=$refreshToken&grant_type=refresh_token"
   try {

       $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token -Method POST -Body $data 

      return $response.access_token;
       
       

   } catch {
    # Dig into the exception to get the Response details.
    # Note that value__ is not a typo.
    Write-Host "StatusCode:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusCode.value__ 
    Write-Host "StatusDescription:" $_.Exception.Response.StatusDescription
    }

   
}
```

Let me know if you have any issues i will see if i cant update it for you.

Comment: Hey @Daimto thank you for the response. Ive actually referenced that guide you linked to several times over the past few days.

So, I tried using that function and I got this error:

`StatusCode: 400`
`StatusDescription: Bad Request`

I updated the URI to use the Authorization endpoint that is provided by Oauth (https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth) and then the function gave me no output. I then saved the output to an html file and it was the same "Required parameter is missing: response_type" error as before.

Comment: This code is really old the endpoints may have changed you should check the [Discovery doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#discovery) for updated endpoints. if your still getting bad request its not sending your post vars properly.  Notices how my prams are built up using& between them like a query string. your not doing that so its not detecting your parms